# What are the sets of vertices in a proper vertex coloring referred to?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

> A (proper) *vertex coloring* of a graph is a labelling of the graph’s vertices with colors such that no two vertices sharing the same edge have the same color.  A coloring using at most $k$ colors is called a (proper) $k$-*coloring*.

The $k$-coloring partitions the vertex set of a graph into $k$ sets.  What do I say to refer to one of these sets of vertices?  For example, "fix a vertex coloring of $G$ and let $A$ be the (blank) of largest order."

Is there a standard terminology?  Also, if there are multiple terms, what other words for these might I see floating around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common term for the collection of vertices receiving the color $i$ is "the $i^\text{th}$ color class" (or just "color class" if you do not wish to specify its color).